# reference object attachement

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, attachment

So i have an object which holds an attachment. this object is pretty much an invoice and has the option to be turned into a pdf document for printing purposes. the invoice will hold an image as an attachment within itself. now i need to figure out how to make the image show up on the pdf? the pdf is a visual force page with renderAs="pdf" on it i need to kno how to reference the attachment of any invoice object when i click the "Print PDF" button on any individual invoice.

Help Please

Comment: Are you talking about displaying an Image within the PDF when it is rendered?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming there's only one Attachment related to the invoice, this will do the trick

```
<apex:page standardController="Invoice__c" renderAs="PDF">

  <apex:repeat value="{!Invoice__c.Attachments}" var="a">
     <apex:image
       height="200px"
       value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, a.Id)}"/>

     <apex:outputText value="{!a.Name}"/>

  </apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: This works now how about if i wanted the name of the file to appear under the image and what if i had more than one attachment but that number could change depending on the object. anywhere between 0 and however many people wanted to put on it.

Comment: the solution works well for multiple attachments, wasnt really sure if you wanted to some more then one. Updated to the code show the Filename was well

Comment: nevermind i got it

Answer (score 1):

In your visualforce page, you would simply need to make reference to the URL of the Image, for example:

```
<img src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015b00000005mrz"/>
```

Where `/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015b00000005mrz` is a reference to an Image stored as a Document within Salesforce.

You need to make sure your image is externally available I believe.

Comment: hmm, think i misunderstood what you wanted